# Internal DNS errors from delegating a subdomains email to GSuite

Tags: domain-name-system, email, exchange

I've outsourced a subdomain for email (say mail.example.com) to gsuite, while wanting to keep my exchange 2003 server authoritative for all of my other domains emails

To the outside world the MX records for mail.example.com are working correctly, however internally – if I want to send (or more importantly forward) emails to mail.example.com I get a DNS failure

'The destination server for this recipient could not be found in Domain Name Service (DNS)'

So .. I'm not an expert & I'm not sure if the problem is resolved by adding MX records under my zone for example.com/having my DNS not use its internal records/root hits or - whether I need to change my outbound SMTP connector in exchange from its catch all(*) to being individually defined to direct the mail subdomain to the gsuite servers

I'm finding it difficult to find information covering this scenario .. All of the above options make some sense as the resolution

My head hurts from researching .. can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Can you send emails to subdomain via OWA?

It seems that have problems with resolving the DNS names, make sure the DNS servers it is talking to can resolve the name.

About changing Send connector address space, there is an article about send connector network settings for your reference. [Send connector network settings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow/connectors/send-connectors?view=exchserver-2019#send-connector-network-settings)